# Need help with calling a page from a button on case

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a page which which shows fields of case in better ui. Now I have to create a button on opp named create case. After clicking create case it should create a case  with some similar fields on opportunity and show the same page. How can i do this??
Any help would be apprecitaed. Please let me know if anything is unclear.
Thanks,
Manohar

Comment: where is that button, on custom VF page or standard page. if it is on VF page, you can do easily with constructor. And if it is on standard page, use AJAX toolkit, it will help you to write queries in JS and there is an option to have a js on button while creating it.

Comment: @YsrShk even standard page custom buttons can reference VF pages, JavaScript custom buttons won't work in LEX.  Quick Actions work well in Chatter feed and LEX

Comment: @Ysr Shk  Thanks for your comment guyz. I made it working.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should  create custom visual force page and controller.

Page:

> apex:page standardController = 'Opportunity' extension='yourCustomController' action="{!createCase}"

and in proper tags insert:

> window.top.location.href = '{!redirectUrl}'.

Controller:
Contsuctor should take (ApexPages.StandardController controller) argument
and then you can take current opportunity with

> controller.getRecord 
>   method.

Then, in controller implement method named createCase which return PageReference Type - in your case, and return there null; In this method you can create your case, and initialize redirectUrl variable by:

> redirectUrl =stdController.view().getUrl();